# C++ - Is destructor called when a vector holds objects?

Tags: destructor

If I dynamically allocate objects of a class inside a vector, is the destructor for each object called if I use clear()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are all cleaned up properly.

From [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/clear/):

> All the elements of the vector are dropped: their destructors are called, and then they are removed from the vector container, leaving the container with a size of 0.

The `[sequence.reqmts]` section of the upcoming standard also makes this clear:

> `a.clear()` destroys all elements in `a`, invalidates all references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of `a` and may invalidate the past-the-end iterator.

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by "dynamically allocate" precisely?  If you use a `vector<foo>` then you are fine.  If you are putting pointers in via `vector<foo*>` then destructors will not get called, because the pointers don't have destructors per se.

Note, however, that in the `vector<foo>` case, you may find your constructors and destructors called a lot more than you expect e.g. when the vector is resized, because the vector will use them when moving the objects in memory if it needs to.  You can use a Boost `shared_ptr` to get around that, though there is a small perf cost due to the reference-count bookkeeping.

My advice: use `vector<foo>` if the objects are cheap to copy and destroy, and `vector<shared_ptr<foo> >` if they're expensive or hard/impossible to copy.  Never use `vector<foo*>` unless you specifically want to avoid having the vector handle memory management, and only then be careful; it's rarely a good idea IMHO.

Comment: If you use move on a object in the container; the object in the container stays but shouldn't be destroyed. What happens then?

Comment: The original answer was written before std::move() was in common use.  What will happen is that the object will still be destroyed.  This is actually the case in general, IIRC -- objects are expected to track when they've been "moved-from" and make their destructors behave appropriately.  The only tricky part is that nobody is supposed to look at the moved-from element's state until it is assigned a new value or destroyed.