# Destructor is called when I push_back to the vector

Tags: c++, vector, destructor

I have this class definition:

```
class FlashStream
{
public:
    explicit FlashStream(const char * url, vector<uint8> * headers, vector<uint8> * data, void * ndata, void * notifyData = NULL, uint32 lastModified = NULL);
    ~FlashStream();
private:        
    NPStream      _stream;
    // ...
}
```

([NPStream description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPStream))

and its implemetation:

```
FlashStream::FlashStream(const char * url, vector<uint8> * headers, vector<uint8> * data, void * ndata, void * notifyData, uint32 lastModified)
{
    // ...
    memset(&_stream, 0, sizeof(NPStream));

    _stream.headers = new char[data->size()]; 

    memcpy((void*)_stream.headers, &(*data)[0], data->size());
    // ...
}

FlashStream::~FlashStream()
{
    // ...
    if(_stream.headers)
        delete [] _stream.headers;
    _stream.headers = NULL;
    // ...
}
```

Now, when I run this code:

```
// ...
vector<FlashStream> _streams;
// ...
_streams.push_back(FlashStream(url, headers, data, _npp.ndata, notifyData, lastModified));
// ...
```

Sometimes I have an error at `delete [] _stream.headers;` in the destructor of `FlashStream`, which is called when I `push_back()` to the `vector<FlashStream> _streams`.

I read [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326246/c-is-destructor-called-when-a-vector-holds-objects) and a few another, but all the same don't know how to elegantly and efficiently fix the problem. May be the problem is in copy constructor, but I don't know how I can make it with memory allocation for `NPStream.headers` and `NPStream.url`?

Comment: The destructor is probably called after the temporary `FlashStream` instance was copied to the vector. I think to get t working correctly, you also should provide the correct (deep-)copy/move behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i don't know how i can make FlashStream copy constructor whith memory allocation for `NPStream.headers` and `NPStream.url`?

Comment: Why are you using pointers for these class members n 1st place?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: `url` could be easily held in a `std::string`, `headers` in a `std::vector<uint8_t>`, a.s.o. ...

Comment: i have additional constructor with `std::string & url` but it changes nothing, because i must allocate memory for `_stream.headers` and `_stream.url`

Comment: In other words: Avoid doing the memory management with `new()`/`delete` on your own. That is hard to get right and error prone.

Comment: Could you show what `NPStream` actually is? I suspect all of your problems could be solved there.

Comment: (NPStream description) link in my question after 1st code block. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPStream

Comment: I see it's a C-API struct. Just create all stuff necessary to initialize the pointers there as plain fields to your class (as mentioned `std::string`, `std::vector<uint8_t>` etc.), and initialize the pointers in a `NPStream` member with their data addresses.

Comment: Thanks, i try this and it seems like it working.

Answer (score 6):

Destructor at `push_back()` could be called in two cases.

- First case, as was noted, occurs when you push a temporary object to the vector. This is not the best idea, since the constructor, copy constructor, and destructor will be called. You may store pointers to object in your vector to avoid redundant calls.

  C++11 comes with new features that might help you.

  - To avoid unnecessary copying, use `std::vector::emplace_back()`. It constructs an object in-place in the vector, instead of copying.
  - Also, you may use the move version of `push_back(value_type&& val)`. Just define a move constructor in your class, and the move version of `push_back()` will work automatically for temporary objects.
- The second case is reaching capacity of the vector. A vector has two major values: a size and a capacity. The size is the number of elements currently held in the vector. The capacity is the number of elements the vector storage can hold. So, when you push back an element, you are increasing the size of the vector. If the capacity is not large enough to hold the new element, the vector performs reallocation to increase its capacity. During reallocation, the vector re-constructs its objects using the copy/move constructor and deletes old objects using the destructor. So, at `push_back()`, the vector could invoke the destructor of the objects multiple times.

To decrease the cost of vector re-sizes at `push_back()`, always use the `std::vector::reserve()` method to pre-allocate the storage for your objects:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(20);
for(int i = 0; i<20; ++i)
    vec.push_back(i)
```

Also, you may decrease the cost of copying objects by defining a move constructor:

```
class C
{
public:
    C(int c)
        : m_c(c)
    {
        std::cout << "C(int c)" << std::endl;
    }
    C(C&& c)
        : m_c(c.m_c)
    {
        std::cout << "C(C&& c)" << std::endl;
    }
    C(const C& c)
        : m_c(c.m_c)
    {
        std::cout << "C(const C& c)" << std::endl;
    }
    ~C()
    {
        std::cout << "~C()" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int m_c;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<C> vc;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        vc.push_back(C(i));
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile and run it, you will see that `C(const C& c)` was not called at all. Since a move constructor is defined, `push_back()` and reallocation will move your objects instead of copying them.

Comment: This should be taken at the correct answer. Too many people are assuming that the temporary variable is the only cause. The reallocation is also a primary cause of the destructor and is likely to appear intermittent due to the hidden growth metric used to calculate the next reallocation.

Answer (score 5):

This statement:

```
_streams.push_back(FlashStream(url, headers, data, _npp.ndata, notifyData, lastModified));
```

is equivalent to:

```
{
    FlashStream temp(url, headers, data, _npp.ndata, notifyData, lastModified);
    _streams.push_back(temp);
    // temp gets destroyed here
}
```

so, you create a temporary FlashStream object that is copied into the vector, then destructed afterwards. You can avoid this by using `emplace_back()` in C++11:

```
_streams.emplace_back(url, headers, data, _npp.ndata, notifyData, lastModified);
```

Comment: I use VS 2010 and must do `_streams.emplace_back(FlashStream(url, headers, data, _npp.ndata, notifyData, lastModified));` and it calls destructor ...

Comment: This is pretty much the same as if you use `push_back`, the correct way (without creating temporaries) to call `emplace_back` is: `_streams.emplace_back(url, headers, data, _npp.ndata, notifyData, lastModified)`. It's possible that VS2010 doesn't have the proper support.

Comment: when i use `_streams.emplace_back(url, headers, data, _npp.ndata, notifyData, lastModified);` compiler generates an error: too many income parameters for function vector<T>::emplace_back() or something like this, becouse in my VS exists only `emplace_back(FlashStream &&_Val)` and `emplace_back(_Valty &&_Val)`

Comment: Then you probably need to add a default constructor that gives you an invalid FlashStream, then create it in the vector e.g. by calling `_streams.resize(_streams.size() + 1);`, and "finishing the job" with either a placement new construction, or a non-constructor init function, like: `_streams.back().init(url, headers, data, _npp.ndata, notifyData, lastModified);`

Comment: It is interesting, but not convenient and contradicts a rule, which reads that a constructor is an object initialization. But, thanks.

Comment: @Slinner _'but not convenient and contradicts a rule'_ Yes, but that's the daily bread and butter, when working with C-APIs :( ...

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a temporary object when you push back.
He's the one which its desctructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

Putting copies of objects in vector/map etc. are bad idea. The destructor called when the temporary objects get destroyed. The destructor for the objects will be again called whenever the Vector/Map resizes or rearranges.

To avoid those you should store pointer to those objects. You may like to use shared_ptrs here.

Comment: I'm not so sure if using `shared_ptr` is the right thing, to fix the OP's design flaws ...

Comment: shared_ptr is not panacea for everything. It won't prevent bugs resulting from erroneous copy constructor etc, but is always better than storing the objects by value.